# Creating a recursive method for counting a specific character in C#

Tags: c#, string, recursion, character

I tried searching within Stackflow to help me answer my question but i did not have any luck since the ones i found are mainly in C++ or Java.
I have recently learned Recursive so please pardon my ability to not understand some terms relating to it.

My question to who ever is able to answer is,what is missing in my code? I need my code to successfully count a specific character within a statement I put in a string. for now my code only prints out the statement.

```
public class CountCharacter
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string s = "most computer students like to play games";
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    public static int countCharacters( string s, char c)
    {
        if (s.Length ==0)
            return 0;
        else if (s[0]==c)
            return 1+ countCharacters(s.Substring(1), 's');
        else
            return 0 + countCharacters (s.Substring(1),'s');
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise counting chars in string recursively, but the teacher thinks otherwise?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I'm assuming this is a programming exercise.

Comment: Well, you're not calling the `countCharacters` method in `Main` for one.  another thing is you need to pass paramcter `c` in as the second parameter in your recursive calls

Comment: In recursion, when you need state (like how many characters), you need to pass the state as a parameter.

Comment: Unless recursion is really what you want, you can simplify the whole function down to one line: `return s.Count(z => z == c);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class CountCharacter
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string s = "most computer students like to play games";
        Console.WriteLine(countCharacters(s, 's'));
    }

    public static int countCharacters( string s, char c)
    {
        if (s.Length == 0)
            return 0;
        else if (s[0] == c)
            return 1 + countCharacters(s.Substring(1), c);
        else
            return countCharacters(s.Substring(1), c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, you fixed 1 bug, but `countCharacters` still isn't called.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally overwrote your edit while approving a suggested edit.

Comment: @David & Asad, tnx for noticing

Comment: and 2nd parameter `char c`?

Comment: @Nenad, very nice :) It's late here i guess.

Comment: That's how you fail on exam! :)

Comment: Just as an FYI, you could simply the entire function down to one line: `return s.Count(z => z == c);`

Answer (score 1):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = " acv jk   ik  ";
            Console.WriteLine("Total space: {0}", CountSpace(s));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int CountSpace(string s)
        {
            if (s.Length > 1)
                return s[0] == ' ' ? 1 + CountSpace(s.Substring(1, s.Length - 1)) : CountSpace(s.Substring(1, s.Length - 1));
            return s[0] == ' ' ? 1 : 0;
        }
```